# connect to tcp server with different port.not a port that is set.c language

Tags: c, linux, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient

i write i tcp client in c language.tcp server is writen in java.Problem is that i set specific port that client use but i connect to  server whit another port not port that i set.
Why this is happen any idea?

connect function is:

```
int CONECT_T0_SERVER(void)
    {
    int iSetOption = 1;

    sock_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    setsockopt(sock_descriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&iSetOption,
            sizeof(iSetOption));

    if(sock_descriptor < 0)
      printf("Failed creating socket\n");

    memset(&sa_loc, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    sa_loc.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa_loc.sin_port = htons(10002);
    sa_loc.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.10.1.30");

    ret = bind(sock_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&sa_loc, sizeof(struct sockaddr));


    bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    server = gethostbyname("10.10.1.120");
   // server = gethostbyname("192.168.123.103");
    //server = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

    if(server == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed finding server name\n");
        return -1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy((char *) &(serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr), (char *)(server->h_addr), server-  >h_length);

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(10000);
    //serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1234);

    if (connect(sock_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect to server\n");
        return -1;
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Connected successfully \n");
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

server port is 10000 and client port is set to 10002 but when i connect to server client port is different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [binding a client to a local port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667763/binding-a-client-to-a-local-port)

Comment: When you get an error, don't just print an arbitrary message you made up yourself. Print `errno`, or `WSAGetLastError(),` or call `perror()`, or use `strerr[].` Otherwise debugging is just a guessing game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size passed to `bind()` is wrong.

Assuming `sa_loc` is declared as:

```
struct sockaddr_in sa_loc;
```

It shall be:

```
ret = bind(sock_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &sa_loc, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

or even better (and **less error prone**):

```
 ret = bind(sock_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &sa_loc, sizeof(sa_loc));
```

---

Btw: It's done correctly in the call to `connect()`.